# Why is running async operations in threads much slower than pure tasks or pure thread operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, async-await

During investigation of some performance issues, we stumbled upon some results that we not know the reason for

We tried running loops of async operations with different loop counts and delays, and we had 3 different constructs, where case 2 ran much slower when the number of threads increased (we would never actually use code like that in case 2, but what are the explanation for the results outlined below):

case 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Delay(delay));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

case 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(delay).Wait(); });
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

case 3:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(delay)));
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

**Why is case 2 so slow compared to the other cases - see output and full program below ?**

```
RunAsync, count = 1, delay = 50
Async execution 1 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0510000, average = 00:00:00.0510000.
RunAsync, count = 5, delay = 50
Async execution 5 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0620000, average = 00:00:00.0124000.
RunAsync, count = 10, delay = 50
Async execution 10 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0660000, average = 00:00:00.0066000.
RunAsync, count = 50, delay = 50
Async execution 50 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0590000, average = 00:00:00.0011800.
RunAsync, count = 100, delay = 50
Async execution 100 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0620000, average = 00:00:00.0006200.
==================================================
RunAsyncInThread, count = 1, delay = 50
Task.Run 1 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0630000, average = 00:00:00.0630000.
RunAsyncInThread, count = 5, delay = 50
Task.Run 5 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0620000, average = 00:00:00.0124000.
RunAsyncInThread, count = 10, delay = 50
Task.Run 10 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.7200000, average = 00:00:00.0720000.
RunAsyncInThread, count = 50, delay = 50

WHY ARE THESE SO SLOW:

Task.Run 50 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:15.8100000, average = 00:00:00.3162000.
RunAsyncInThread, count = 100, delay = 50
Task.Run 100 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:34.0600000, average = 00:00:00.3406000.
==================================================
RunThread, count = 1, delay = 50
Thread execution 1 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0500000, average = 00:00:00.0500000.
RunThread, count = 5, delay = 50
Thread execution 5 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0500000, average = 00:00:00.0100000.
RunThread, count = 10, delay = 50
Thread execution 10 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0500000, average = 00:00:00.0050000.
RunThread, count = 50, delay = 50
Thread execution 50 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.0500000, average = 00:00:00.0010000.
RunThread, count = 100, delay = 50
Thread execution 100 times with Task.Delay of 50 ms. took 00:00:00.1000000, average = 00:00:00.0010000.
```

The full test program is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync(1, 50);
            RunAsync(5, 50);
            RunAsync(10, 50);
            RunAsync(50, 50);
            RunAsync(100, 50);
            Console.WriteLine("==================================================");
            RunAsyncInThread(1, 50);
            RunAsyncInThread(5,50);
            RunAsyncInThread(10,50);
            RunAsyncInThread(50,50);
            RunAsyncInThread(100,50);
            Console.WriteLine("==================================================");
            RunThread(1, 50);
            RunThread(5,50);
            RunThread(10,50);
            RunThread(50,50);
            RunThread(100,50);

            //RunAsyncInThread(20, 50);
            //RunAsyncInThread(40, 50);
            //RunAsyncInThread(80, 50);
            //RunAsyncInThread(160, 50);
            //RunAsyncInThread(320, 50);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter:");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void RunAsyncInThread(int count, int delay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunAsyncInThread, count = {0}, delay = {1} ", count, delay);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(delay).Wait(); });
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            var elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - now;
            Console.WriteLine("Task.Run {0} times with Task.Delay of {1} ms. took {2}, average = {3}. ", count, delay, elapsed, TimeSpan.FromTicks(elapsed.Ticks / count));
        }

        private static void RunAsync(int count, int delay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunAsync, count = {0}, delay = {1} ",count,delay);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Delay(delay));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            var elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - now;
            Console.WriteLine("Async execution {0} times with Task.Delay of {1} ms. took {2}, average = {3}. ", count, delay, elapsed, TimeSpan.FromTicks(elapsed.Ticks / count));
        }

        private static void RunThread(int count, int delay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunThread, count = {0}, delay = {1} ",count,delay);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(delay)));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            var elapsed = DateTime.UtcNow - now;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread execution {0} times with Task.Delay of {1} ms. took {2}, average = {3}. ", count, delay, elapsed, TimeSpan.FromTicks(elapsed.Ticks / count));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `DateTime.Now` to time how long something takes.  It doesn't have sufficient precision or accuracy to meaningfully do that.  Use `Stopwatch`.

Comment: The times look like case 2 is the fastest, by far, in contrast with your statement.  The first and third are the slow ones...

Comment: You are gumming up the threadpool with the waits.  ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 4) is the sledgehammer solution but it is a structural issue that should be addressed.  Hard to reverse-engineer from the artificial test code.

Comment: Servy is quite correct, you've mixed up the cases. Using `Task.Run(() => { Task.Delay(delay).Wait(); }` is slowest. It seems to be running sequentially. I'm not quite sure why Sleep behaves differently than Wait, but Wait is going to block on an internal ManualResetEventSlim. I believe that actually does a SpinWait internally which could be part of the issue.

Comment: Yes I had mixed case 1 and case 2 up. sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is it slower to schedule a thread pool thread to start an asynchronous operation, and then sit there waiting for that asynchronous operation to finish, instead of just doing the asynchronous operation directly?

You save the overhead of waiting for the operation to be scheduled in the thread pool, and if the thread pool is saturated, say because you flooded it with a hundred requests all of a sudden, this could take some time.  Once the operation is scheduled it can finally *start* to execute the asynchronous operation.

Why is it slower to create an entirely new thread so that you can start an asynchronous operation and then wait for it to finish instead of just starting an asynchronous operation?

Because you need to spend all of the time and effort to create a brand new thread, and wait for it to get scheduled for the first time before you can even *start* your asynchronous operation.

Comment: yes I agree, but difference between case 2 and 3 that both start lots of threads is still very big.

Comment: @StigSchmidtNielsson Yes.  They'll behave differently in different situations; that's a direct result of pooling the threads.  It means that less time is wasted spinning up new threads, because a smaller number of threads can be re-used, but it also means that when you oversaturate the pool with more work than it can handle, it'll perform even worse.  You're pretty much doing exactly the type of thing that the thread pool is least capable of handling; you're using it's least acceptable patterns of adding work.